# Why can't lualatex in MiKTeX find stmaryrd fonts unless pdflatex is run first?

Tags: luatex, miktex, luaotfload, acmart, stmaryrd

MNWE:

```
\documentclass{acmart}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\begin{document}
$\Mapsto$
\end{document}
```

Running `lualatex` on this file gives a log containing

```
luaotfload | cache : Lookup cache loaded from C:/Users/Jason/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/luatex-cache/generic-dev/names/luaotfload-lookup-cache.luc.
luaotfload | db : Reload initiated (formats: otf,ttf,ttc); reason: "Font stmary9
 not found.".
luaotfload | resolve : sequence of 3 lookups yielded nothing appropriate.
luaotfload | resolve : sequence of 3 lookups yielded nothing appropriate.
Missing character: There is no Z (U+005A) in font stmary9!
```

What does this mean?  And, perhaps more confusingly, why does it disappear if I run `pdflatex` on my document before running `lualatex`?

(Perhaps this last has something to do with the `pdflatex` log entry

```
miktex-maketfm: security risk: running with elevated privileges
Making stmary9.tfm from "D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts/source/public/stmaryrd\stmary9.mf"...
Running miktex-mf.exe...
miktex-mf: security risk: running with elevated privileges
This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (MiKTeX 2.9.7400 64-bit)

(D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts/source/public/stmaryrd\stmary9.mf
```

?)

Full `lualatex` log available [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/JasonGross/b02bac23e17b541c6a3f613f19b64933/raw/6907283838bc19a397b89a84502c6232eef4a616/lualatex.log), full `pdflatex` log available [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/JasonGross/b02bac23e17b541c6a3f613f19b64933/raw/6907283838bc19a397b89a84502c6232eef4a616/pdflatex.log).

Comment: That is the fault of `acmart`.  If you replace that by `article` there is no such message.

Comment: Oh, and try deleting the LuaTeX font cache.

Comment: I think there is a duplicate somewhere about this. Luatex doesn't trigger the tfm creation for such fonts.